# How to fix javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException with Omnifaces 1.14.1

Tags: java, jsf, omnifaces

We have an JSF 2.0 web application, running on a WAS 8.5, in which we are using the Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory. Nothing else from Omnifaces is used in the remaining application. The UI is based on the Primefaces framework.

The application starts properly but on some actions (Change Tab within the application, press a button) there occures the following exception:

```
000000d2 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [FacesServlet] in application [<anonymized>]. Exception created : [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: Provider javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory: wsjar:file:/<anonymized>/lib/Saxon-HE-9.5.1-1.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:186)
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:162)
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.checkInitialized(WebXml.java:388)
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.findErrorPageLocation(WebXml.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.findErrorPageLocation(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:418)
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handleAjaxException(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:350)
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:322)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:509)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1238)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3490)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:4077)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: Provider javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory: wsjar:file:/<anonymized>/lib/Saxon-HE-9.5.1-1.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:175)
    ... 39 more
```

If I comment out the dependency in the pom.xml and the factory in the faces-config.xml. The application works fine.

Here the entry in the faces-config.xml

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
  </factory>
```

Is there any idea, from where the incompatibility comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any idea, from where the incompatibility comes from?

The incompatibility comes from a dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.5.1-1</version>
</dependency>
```

The Saxon-HE-9.5.1-1.jar contains a service /META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory which contains lines ilegally having spaces in it:

```
net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl
http\://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom:    net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl
http\://saxon.sf.net/jaxp/xpath/om:     net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl
```

This fails in the `javax.xml.xpath.ServiceLoader.parseLine` method:

```
....
if ((ln.indexOf(' ') >= 0) || (ln.indexOf('\t') >= 0))
                fail(service, u, lc, "Illegal configuration-file syntax");
....
```

Try to upgrade your Saxon-HE version as [9.5.1-1 is rather old (2013)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.5.1-1) and seemes to be simply not Java 8+ compatible.

Version 9.5.1-5 is the [first version with this bug fixed](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.5/).

```
The following bugs are cleared in 9.5.1.5, issued 2014-03-25
...
1944 Illegal configuration-file syntax in META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory
```

[Issue 1944](https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1944)